# Firebase Analytics user_engagement events not captured

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have integrated firebase analytics in my android application. Screen views are captured correctly. But user_engagement events are not captured which is supposed to be captured automatically as user stay on the screen for every 10 second by default.

Comment: Contact Firebase support directly if an Firebase SDK doesn't behave the way you expect.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

The user_engagement event will automatically be triggered when the app is in the foreground state for a period of time. To verify if your implementation is correct, please [enable the verbose logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#enabling_debug_mode) for your app and use the [DebugView console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#reporting). Switching the app from foreground state to background state to foreground state should trigger the event. If the issue persists, then reach out to Firebase support.